# Not able to create a multisampled framebuffer

Tags: opengl, glsl, framebuffer

I am trying to blit a custom framebuffer of size 1920 X 1080 to default frame buffer of size 800 X 600.

The window is created with following options

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_FLOATING , GLFW_TRUE);  
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
   glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "Renderer", nullptr, nullptr);   // Create the render window
glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

I first create a texture object.

```
// create a texture object
    glGenTextures(1, &textureMsaaId);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, textureMsaaId);
    glTexImage2DMultisample(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, 4, GL_RGBA8, 1920, 1080, false);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, 0);
```

Create the frame buffer

```
     glGenFramebuffers(1, &fboMsaaId);
     glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboMsaaId);
    // create a 4x MSAA renderbuffer object for depthbuffer
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rboDepthId);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboDepthId);
    glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, 4, 1920, 1080);

    // attach msaa  Texture and RBO to FBO attachment points
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, textureMsaaId, 0);  
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboDepthId);
    GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    if (status == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        qDebug() << "Frame buffer Completed";
    else
        qDebug() << "Frame buffer NOT Completed";

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

I get the error that frame buffer is not comlete.

The error is GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT , which is caused due to render buffer attachment.

Comment: And what is the reason for it being incomplete? That `status` value is kind of important. Also, it's not clear why you're rendering to a multisample FBO, then trying to blit that to a default framebuffer that is *also* multisampled. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas i want a framebuffer of size 1920 X 1080 but want the display window of size 800 X 600.

Comment: the error is GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT

Comment: "*i want a framebuffer of size 1920 X 1080 but want the display window of size 800 X 600.*" You cannot do any rescaling if the source or destination contains multiple samples. So you need to do the multisample resolve *first*, then rescale the result for the window (which should not be multsampled). This isn't the problem you're encountering, but your overall approach does not work.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas if the defualt window is not multisampled than can i blit like this ?

Comment: glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fboMsaaId);
  glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
  glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK);
  glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, 1920, 1080,  // src rect
   0, 0, 800, 600,  // dst rect
   GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, // buffer mask
   GL_NEAREST);

Comment: Not if the source framebuffer is multisampled. That's why I said "source ***or*** destination," not "and". You can only do rescaling if *neither* framebuffer is multisampled.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas thanks i  understand what you mean.

Comment: You have swapped the *samples* and *internalformat* argument in [`glRenderbufferStorageMultisample`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glRenderbufferStorageMultisample.xhtml). It has to be `glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 4, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, 1920, 1080);`

Comment: @Rabbid76 indeed i had swapped the samples and the internal format , and also i had to set the value of the last parameter of glTexImage2DMultisample to true , which i found out from one of your answer given to a question.